# 'TextBlob' object has no attribute 'detect_language'

Tags: python, google-translate, textblob

i used : words=TextBlob(text_)
lan=words.detect_language() in my code and it displays TextBlob object has no attribute detect_language as error
i have tried various modifications from chatgpt and other sites....still facing same error